# Как сделать пополнение очереди и отправку задания потокам? Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, очередь

Такая ситуация возникла, не могу найти решение. Пишу многопоточный парсер, ссылки которые нужно обработать постоянно генерируются. Мне нужно реализовать раздачу этих ссылок потокам. Решил сделать через threading и queue. Написал такой код, для примера. В данном коде мне нужно каким-то образом, понять когда очередь стало пустой, пополнить ее и заставить потоки выполнить над ней какую-то функцию.

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import random



class Downloader(threading.Thread):
  

    def __init__(self, queue):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        while True:
  
            num = self.queue.get()

            self.output(url)

            # Отправляем сигнал о том, что задача завершена
            self.queue.task_done()

    def output(self, url):
        print(url, threading.current_thread())

def generate():
    number.append(random.randrange(1, 10, 1))

def main(numbers):
    """
    Запускаем программу
    """
    queue = Queue()

    # Запускаем потом и очередь
    for i in range(2):
        t = Downloader(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    # 
    for num in numbers:
        queue.put(num)
    # Ждем завершения работы очереди

    queue.join()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

      main(number)
```

Comment: Что значит "ссылки постоянно генерируются" ? Может их по мере генерации сразу все складывать в очередь и все. Если конечно их не огромное количество, что бы забить всю память

Comment: Хотя очереди можно задать размер и тогда put в нее заблокируется когда она полна и отработает только когда в ней место появиться и тогда "понимать" когда она станет пустой вообще не нужнол

Comment: Ну можно проверять `qsize()`, если он стал меньше определённого размера - дополнять очередь новыми заданиями.

Comment: @Mike можете подсказать каким образом задать размер очереди? И если она будет полная не будет ли ошибок или q.put() будет ждать, пока она освободится?

Comment: Согласно документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html при создании объекта очереди размер передается как параметр. Там же и про put сказано "Put item into the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until a free slot is available"

Comment: Большое спасибо, с проблемой справился!